# Thickbox --> IE8 --> Google Map Problem

Tags: internet-explorer-8, thickbox

we are using the solution from mapmaker.donkeymagic.co.uk to create a google map that is then being embeded into a webpage.

An example of it working is here

http://www.fairlieyachtclub.com/erracms/pages/contact.aspx?articleid=15&zoneid=16

Now.... in ie6/ie7/ie8 compatibility mode/firefox3+

The map works correctly when the image is clicked

The map is loaded into the thickbox application and works as we expect

However... in ie8 the map does not load

Can somebody assist in troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

Même problème d'affichage sous IE8, une GoogleMap ouverte dans Thickbox ne s'affichait pas complètement, le lien suivant m'a permi de résoudre cela rapidement :

[Bug avec Google Map et Thickbox 3](http://www.korben.info/bug-avec-google-map-et-thickbox-3.html)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, at the moment of posting this comment the link is not working. Also the site is down, can ping the site, retrieve IP.

But cannot access the site....